# reading csv from s3 bucket with lambda (python) and splitting into separate lines

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Tried a couple of the solutions here but nothing works for me and I dont know what I am doing.
I have a file in an s3 bucket called bats.csv
This is what the contents look like:

```
 Ticker Exchange    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
 6A     BATS    12/2/2021   0.7103  0.712   0.6993  0.6999  113073
 6A     BATS    12/3/2021   0.7103  0.712   0.6993  0.6999  113073
 6A     BATS    12/4/2021   0.7103  0.712   0.6993  0.6999  113073
```

This code below seems to work somewhat when I test it but I get a null response, and then I see the data in the function logs below.

```
 import boto3
 import json

 s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
 S3_BUCKET = 'olaptrader-products'
 #S3_PREFIX = ''

 def lambda_handler(event, context):
     object_key = "bats.csv"  # replace object key
     file_content = s3_client.get_object(
     Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=object_key)["Body"].read()
     print(file_content)
```

When I test the function, all I get is a null, but below in the Function Logs, I do see the data, except that its not split into different lines.
Just wondering why I am getting a null response? And if this is not the proper way to split the lines, please advise.
[image]

After suggestion from "lastber" I am getting responses

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
S3_BUCKET = 'olaptrader-products'
#S3_PREFIX = ''
  
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    object_key = "bats.csv"  # replace object key
    file_content = s3_client.get_object(
    Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=object_key)["Body"].read()
    lines = file_content.decode().splitlines()
    print(lines)
    return{
    "body": json.dumps(lines)
    }
```

My json results looks like this, which isnt great

{
"body": "["Ticker,Exchange,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume", "6A,BATS,12/2/2021,0.7103,0.712,0.6993,0.6999,113073", "6A,BATS,12/3/2021,0.7103,0.712,0.6993,0.6999,113073", "6A,BATS,12/4/2021,0.7103,0.712,0.6993,0.6999,113073"]"
}

So, my question is this:
If I want to offer the ability of customers to pull data in csv or json, maybe I need to actually store a copy of the data in both formats?. This data above, which is pulled from csv, doesnt look correct when compared to what I want a json result to looks like below:

[{"Ticker":"6A","Exchange":"BATS","date":"2021-12-02","open":0.7103,"high":0.712,"low":0.6993,"close":0.6999,"volume":113073},{"Ticker":"6A","Exchange":"BATS","date":"2021-12-03","open":0.7103,"high":0.712,"low":0.6993,"close":0.6999,"volume":113073}]

a csv is only going to have that one header row, whereas, the json will have the Ticker, Exchange, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume in EACH row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `null` response because your `lambda_handler` does not return anything in a `return` statement.

With regards to splitting the lines, try reading the file with a python [CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to simplify data access.

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to offer both csv and json to subscribers, do you think I would need to keep a copy of both, or could I transform the csv to json on the fly if the subscriber wanted json?

Comment: This will depend on the pattern of user access, the frequency the unerlying data changing, tolerance of the users to work with stale data, as well as a few other questions related to the overall problem you are trying to solve.  So any credible answer to your question cannot be given without taking this all into consideration.